# Можно с css изогнуть блок прямоугольник в формы подковы?

Tags: css

Из такого блока как бы практически круг 270 градусов

[image: Из такого блока как бы практически круг 270 градусов]

Чтоб допустим такой прогресс бар был полукруглым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему-то мне думается, что вы пытаетесь изобразить подкову именно [такой формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240455/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80). Да?

Если нет, то на CSS это возможно, но иначе, чем в примере ниже.

Если да, то вот результат:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 40px solid black;
  border-radius: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 55%, 0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 50% 55%, 0 90%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Отвечая на вопрос:

> Можно с css изогнуть блок прямоугольник в формы подковы?

Ответ: однозначно - да.